# Url.Action error dont exist object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have Script

```
$(function() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://example.com/WCFRESTService.svc/GetCategories',
        success: function(result) {
            var s = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                s += '<br><a href="@Url.Action("GetAnn", "Home",new { categories_id=result[i]["Categories_id"]})">' + result[i]["Name_Category"] + '</a>';
                $('#content').html(s);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The `Url.Action` Gives an error on `result[i]["Categories_id"]`.

> The name "result" does not exist int the current context

How do I transfer to my object result?

Comment: you are mixing c# and js code. you will need to set the href to the generated url - `/Home/GetAnn?.....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass JavaScript(Client Side) variable to `Url.Action` as it is processed at the Server-Side.

As a workaround, you can use placeholder to generate the url. Then use `.replace()` method to generate the actual url.

```
var s = '';
//Generate a variable with URL
var url = '@Url.Action("GetAnn", "Home", new { categories_id = -1})'; 
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    s += '<br><a href="' + url.replace(-1, result[i]["Categories_id"]) + '">' + result[i]["Name_Category"] + '</a>';
    $('#content').html(s);
}
```